# Ubuntu xrdp mate desktop display problem - I am seeing double

Tags: remote-desktop, mate

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 on a machine. I installed the Mate desktop , as I prefer it to the Gnome. I then installed xrdp and connected with no problem, but I had the Gnome desktop. I followed the recommendations of this site:
https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/07/ubuntu-1804-xrdp-mate-en/

Next time I connected through xrdp, I got the mate-desktop, but it is like I am seeing double in the top bar of the desktop.

Has anyone out there seen this issue and resolved it?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it is the real simple things that does it just like restarting the photocopier...In this instance, all I had to do was to go in the Control Center -> Appearance -> Mate Tweak and change the Panel from Mutiny to Traditional and then back to Mutiny. Problem solved.